# How do i change change width of a div that is placed in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

i had a div that is placed inside an iframe i tried using jquery

```
$('#navframe').contents().find('.FtrMapSctn').css("width","30%")
```

but this fails can any one help me please

Comment: is the iframe content on the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is all in the same domain, you may have to wait for your iFrame to load:

```
$("#navframe").load(function() {
    $(this).contents().find('.FtrMapSctn').css("width","30%");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yours is correct syntax.

But that line works fine  if the I `frame` belongs  is in the same domain as your `page`, otherwise browser wont allow it for security reasons.

And If same domain,write a call back to load event and do your job there.

```
window.onload = function() {
    parent.invokeMyJob();
}
```

and

```
function invokeMyJob() {
    $(this).contents().find('.FtrMapSctn').css("width","30%");
}
```